# API requests increases Visit counts on Website

Tags: php

I am using Pagespeed api by its uri as (php),

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=" . urlencode($pageurl) . "&pp=1&key=" . $key . "&strategy=desktop
```

But, when I do the same for more pages of a website, the page visit count gets increased as per the number of requests made.

Is there any way by which i can use the same method but the visit count dosen't get register ?

I came to know that visit count is registered by the name of "Google Inc" when i saw the live Google Analysis Data of my site.

Please help. Its Urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell from the client ip (via whois lookup) or the user-agent if it's Google (and most other bots).

Comment: Have a look at some of the open-source log analyzers like awstats